# how to create current date with datepicker and how to filter it and how to add that date to object in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, date, object, filter, addition

In my project we are using Angular. I tried with new date object some how i get current date and time but i need only date .
And that date should be add to an object how????

$scope.date=new Date();

It gives date and time but i need only date with required format.

### in HTML

{{date}}
  In my project we are using Angular. I tried with new date object some how i get current date and time but i need only date .
And that date should be add to an object how????

$scope.date=new Date();

It gives date and time but i need only date with required format.

### in HTML

{{date}}

Comment: you need to fetch your date from $scope.date....jus google it there is a lot of stuff available

Comment: May be you post your query twice in this question. please update your question. please take a tour http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

You could just use the date filter in angular with the format you need.

More options on [Angular Date Filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date)

```js
var app = angular.module("sampleApp", []);

app.controller("sampleController", ["$scope",
  function($scope) {
    $scope.date = new Date();
  }
]);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="sampleApp">
  <div ng-controller="sampleController">
    {{ date | date : 'MM-d-yyyy'}}
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: can you eloborate please?